# Using $(this) to find items in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i have multiple of the same forms on one page.

I am doing a countdown of chars until the comment button is enabled.

What i have works some what, but i need help with making it only relevant to the current form.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vN7e5/

If there is only one form on the page it works fine.

I previously used

```
$(this).next
```

to make sure only the submit button in the current form was affected, but this doesnt work for the comment text box or the count down span.

Any help? Thanks!

Incase of jsfiddle error:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    disableComments();
    $( ".addpostcomment" ).keyup(function() {
        disableComments();
        $(this).next('.addcommentbutton').prop('disabled', !($(this).val().length > 20));
    });

    function disableComments() {
        var commentLength = $(".addpostcomment").val().length;
        var remainingCommentLength = 20 - commentLength;
        if (remainingCommentLength > 0) {
            $('.countdownCommentLength').show();
            $('.countdownCommentLength').text(remainingCommentLength + ' character(s) until minimum reached.');
        } else {
            $('.countdownCommentLength').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Form:

```
<form class="addcomment" action="process/addcomment.php" method="post">
        <div class="commentappend">
        <input type="hidden" class="postid" name="postid" value="' . $postID . '">
        <input type="hidden" class="usernameuser" name="usernameuser" value="' . $usernameuser . '">
        <input type="hidden" class="userid" name="userid" value="' . $userid . '">
        <input type="hidden" class="buildid" name="buildid" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '">
        </div>

        <div class="commentbutton">
        <input type="text" maxlength="250" name="addpostcomment" class="addpostcomment" placeholder="Add Comment... (max 60 characters)" />
        <input type="submit" id="addcommentbutton" class="addcommentbutton" value="Post" disabled/>
        </div>
        <br />
        <span class="countdownCommentLength"></span>

    </form>
```

Comment: Your `disableComments()` function works on all .countdownCommentLength classes at the same time. You probably want to pass the .addpostcomment being worked on as an argument, i.e., `$(".addpostcomment" ).keyup(function() { disableComments($(this)); ... ` and use that in the disableComments function. You also initialize the initial text using that function, so then you do want it to work on everything. So you probably also need a separate initialization function. Good luck~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    disableComments();
    $( ".addpostcomment" ).keyup(function() {
        var form = this.form;
        disableComments(form);
        $('.addcommentbutton', form).prop('disabled', !($(this).val().length > 20));
    });

    function disableComments(form) {
        var commentLength = $(".addpostcomment", form).val().length;
        var remainingCommentLength = 20 - commentLength;
        var commentDisplay = $('.countdownCommentLength', form);
        if (remainingCommentLength > 0) {
            commentDisplay.show()
                .text(remainingCommentLength + ' character(s) until minimum reached.');
        } else {
            commentDisplay.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

You need to use a scope to limit which elements you're selecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using parent/child relationships. For example, you have a form like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text"/><button disabled>Post</button><br>
    <label>20 more characters required</label>
</form>
```

By using `$(this).parent("form").find("button")`, I can get access to the button in the same form as the input.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[type='text']").keyup(function(){

        if($(this).val().length > 19)
        {
            $(this).parent("form").find("label").html("Requirement met");
            $(this).parent("form").find("button").attr("disabled", false);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent("form").find("label").html((20 - $(this).val().length) + " more characters required");
            $(this).parent("form").find("button").attr("disabled", true);
        }

    });

});
```

### [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77vWF/)

Answer (score 0):

you could simplify the identification of form elements a bit by doing something along these lines

```
$(':text').on('keyup', function() {
    var btn = $(this).siblings(':submit');
    if($(this).val().length >= 20) {
        btn.prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        btn.prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```